# Add strings together through linq query

Tags: linq

I'm trying to combine the values, if multiple owner id it'll add the line values together.

http://i.snag.gy/fOWWQ.jpg

With the image Given, if my query is ran I would end up with

http://i.snag.gy/qO1DO.jpg

What I've tried so far

```
from Person in TargetGroups
group Person by Person.PersonId into g
select new {g.PersonId, g.Value}
```

Comment: Post your sample data in the text format. No need to include them as images stored on a different server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to concatenate values of `Car` column like this:

```
TargetGroups
.GroupBy(x => x.PersonId)
.Select(x => new { PersonId = x.Key, Cars = string.Join(",", x.Select(a => a.Car)) });
```

*Query* syntax:

```
from Person in TargetGroups
group Person by Person.PersonId into g
select new {  PersonId =  g.Key, Cars = string.Join(",", g.Select(x => x.Car)) }
```

Comment: Definitely like your approach, producing a red highlight of string.join() `anonymous type projection initializers should be simple name or member access expression`

Comment: @user3276954 okey then try giving names to properties